# How to create the Channel Credentials object in Grpc.Core.Api.dll using LabVIEW .NET constructor Node?

Tags: .net, dll, grpc, abstract, labview

I tried to use the Grpc.Core.Api.dll, build from the C# nu get Package for the Channel Credentials using LabVIEW .NET constructor node but it throws an error telling 'can't create an instance for the abstract class.
How to resolve it so that I can set channel credentials for the gRPC in LabVIEW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create an instance of an *ABSTRACT* class object. From the [windows C# guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members):

> The abstract keyword enables you to create classes and class members that are incomplete and **must** be implemented in a derived class.

What you are trying to create through the constructor node is therefore not a fully formed object, but more of a framework that other classes can be built upon.